# How work git ls-files script

Tags: python, git

Hows look script which do `git ls-files`?
It possible to repair index file or extract list of files from corupted index file?
Maybe possible with regex?  preferably in python 2.7.6

Comment: You want to find where your existing `git-ls-files` binary is? Or write a new script which does exactly the same thing as that? _Why_? How does this relate to your corrupted index file? Which actual file is that - `.git/index`? Something else?

Comment: Yes i need write a new script which does exactly the same thing as git-ls-files, as i need only extract files list from .git/index file (not matter it corrupted or not), without checking bad signature, hash and something else just raw files list without garbage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the level of corruption this may or may not be doable. The data structure and related tooling of Git are more attuned to detecting corruption than fixing it.

In particular, the index itself is not part of the repository, it is derived from the current contents, so in most cases you will probably be better off deleting it and doing `git reset` to recreate it. Whoever reads your question is probably wondering how your repository got into that state.

With that in mind, here are a couple thoughts:

The last 20 bytes of the index are a sha1 of the file contents up to that point. If those are corrupt you could overwrite them using a hex editor.

```
~$ python3
>>> data = open('.git/index', 'rb').read()
>>> data[-20:].hex()
'e211d8f60209ca8571c2acc73f9a24ef523b5fa3'
>>> hashlib.sha1(data[:-20]).hexdigest()
'e211d8f60209ca8571c2acc73f9a24ef523b5fa3'
```

This may fix simple corruption caused by a brain-damaged tool.

If you really want to recover anything you can from a totally corrupt index file, you would probably want to:

1. Read [index-format.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt) in the reference implementation.
2. Look at the `parse_index` routine in [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/15e119375018fba121cf58e02a9f17fe22df0df8/src/index.c#L2454).
3. Look at the specific error your index file causes.
4. Carefully patch that routine to keep going on bad data without crashing.

Another approach could be to use the [strings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/strings.1.html) utility, if you just want to see a list of filenames. You'll lose the relevant binary information (and some of the binary information will contain printable ASCII junk).

Comment: strings a not very bad but also a lot of garbage